# Call Client method outside SignalR Project

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, signalr, signalr.client

I am having concerns about how to use SgnalR in the following scenario:

There is a non-hub service project that runs a time-consuming task periodically. 
The clients should be notified about the progress of the running task. After making some research, SignalR seemed to be the right choice for this purpose.

The problem is, I want the Service-Hub-Clients system to be as loosely-coupled as possible. So, I hosted the Hub in IIS and as a SignalR documentation suggests, added a reference to the Hub context in the outside project and called the client method:

```
    hubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<TheHub>()
    hubContext.Clients.All.progress(n, i);
```

Client side:

```
    private void InitHub()
    {
        hubConnection = new HubConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["hubConnection"]);

        hubProxy = hubConnection.CreateHubProxy("TheHub");
        hubConnection.Start().Wait();
    }

    hubProxy.On<int, int>("progress", (total, done) =>
        {
            task1Bar.Invoke(t => t.Maximum = total);
            task1Bar.Invoke(t => t.Value = done);
        });
```

On the client side the method isn't being invoked and after two days of research I can't get it working, although when making a call from the Hub itself, it works fine. I suspect I'm missing some configuration

Comment: Can you show us some more code about how you create the `HubConnection` and `IHubProxy`

Comment: Hi, Michael. I added the code above

Comment: Ok, normally this should work. Check if `n` and `i` are both of type `int`. Furthermore overload `Task OnConnected` method in `TheHub` and check by adding a breakpoint if after `hubConnection.Start()` the brakepoint gets hit.

Comment: I have already checked this, the breakpoint gets hit in OnConnected as well as in any other method I added to TheHub class. The problem raises when trying to do the same outside the Hub project

Comment: Normally this should work. One more issue could be if you dispose the `IDisposable` returned by `On`.

Comment: I've just tried to make a call from the outside of Hub class, but in the same project and it worked. Can it be some issue with app.domain?

Comment: I think you might be deadlocking yourself on the client because you are using .Wait() and when Start() completes it cannot jump back on the UI thread. Try making your calls async and await async methods.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use the GlobalHost.Connection manager in your Hub class or service, if the caller is going to be any project other than the Web project.

```
GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<TheHub>()
```

You should instead create a service class that would abstract the hub from the callers. The service class should have something like:

```
// This method is what the caller sees, and abstracts the communication with the Hub
public void NotifyGroup(string groupName, string message)
{
  Execute("NotifyGroup", groupName, message);
}

// This is the method that calls the Hub
private void Execute(string methodName, params object[] parameters)
{
  using (var connection = new HubConnection("http://localhost/"))
  {
    _myHub = connection.CreateHubProxy("TheHub");
    connection.Start().Wait();
    _myHub.Invoke(methodName, parameters);
    connection.Stop();
  }
}
```

The last bit which is the hub itself, should be something like:

```
public void NotifyGroup(string groupName, string message)
{
  var group = Clients.Group(groupName);
  if (group == null)
  {
    Log.IfWarn(() => $"Group '{groupName}' is not registered");
    return;
  }
  group.NotifyGroup(message);
}
```